# Python URL shortener background app suggestion

Tags: python, autohotkey, url-shortener

I have written a python script which uses Google's URL shortener API to shorten URLs.
But I want that script to automatically shorten URLs whenever they're copied.

- Are there any better ideas than running a Python script or AHK script
  in the background to check if the clipboard content is a long URL?
- Will AHK script take lesser CPU usage than Python script when running in
  background?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In AHK you can use a label named [**OnClipboardChange**](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/OnClipboardChange.htm),
for checking the contents of the clipboard, whenever they change.

- To search the clipboard contents for a given occurrence of a
  specified string, you can use commands such as

  **[If InStr](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/InStr.htm)**(clipboard, "SearchString")

  **If** clipboard [**contains**](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/IfIn.htm)
  SearchString1,SearchString2
- To change/shorten the contents of the clipboard, if it contains the
  specified SearchString(s),you can use commands such as

  [**StringReplace**](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/StringReplace.htm), clipboard, clipboard, SearchString, NewString

  [**RegExReplace**()](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/RegExReplace.htm)

The CPU usage of such an AHK script is minimal.